# iphone how to use Three20 save photo?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I use `Three20` library to create application like photo album browser.

My Questions is how to use `Three20` to save images? or by using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` to save images?

I hope you provide me with some code.

Thanks,
And sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, please see the following link:

[How do you use TTURLCache to save images to disk?](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/4b8753312f440c0e/a6f47ef5f12ffd5d)

Good luck.